# Call API from .NETCOre3.1 returns The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: iis, postman, cross-domain, asp.net-core-3.1, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to call an web page with SSL certificate  as you can see below :

```
 public string GetToken()
    {



            using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls;

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                {

                    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("https://pgsb.iran.gov.ir").Result;

                    return "ok";

                }
            }

    }
```

When I call my controller in .NETCore 3.1  I get this error.

[image]

When I call the website using POSTMAN success response returned But when I call the website using .NETCORE hosted by IIS I get the above error .

As a detail I want to add when I call the website using Angular I get this error in console windows :

```
no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Why do you want to change ˋ  httpClientHandler.SslProtocols`?

Comment: Can you view specific error messages? Is TLS 1.0 used in IIS?